# graphite storage-schemas match a pattern with two wildcard segments

Tags: regex, graphite

I am creating metrics which have the following pattern:

```
MyApp.<environment>.<hostname>.DB.some_metric
```

The metric must start with "MyApp" and the third segment should be "DB".  How do I specify a pattern with two wildcarded segments?

I've tried

```
MyApp\.*\.*\.DB\.
```

and

```
MyApp\.*\.DB\.
```

but neither are matching.  The creates log is showing that new metrics are being matched to the default schema.

I have other applications with different retention policies that also have a "DB" segment so a pattern like `\.DB\.` would not be specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the following pattern:

```
pattern = ^MyApp\..*\.DB\.
```

The extra period helped match any string between the two segments of known values.